# Install a Puppet module to the global modules directory by default?

Tags: puppet

I'm setting up a Puppet master server for the first time. It's configured to use environments:

**/etc/puppet/puppet.conf**:

```
[main]
environmentpath = /var/opt/puppet/environments
basemodulepath = /var/opt/puppet/modules
```

Whenever I install a module, `puppet module install foo`, it get installed into my "production" environment's module directory. What I want to happen is for the module to be installed to `/var/opt/puppet/modules` unless I specify an environment with the `--environment` switch.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

As of the current Puppet version (v6.0):

> By default, this command installs modules into the **first directory** in
>   the Puppet modulepath, which defaults to
>   $codedir/environments/production/modules.

That means you need to set the modulepath so that '/var/opt/puppet/modules' is the first directory in your modulepath. Since the modulepath setting can only be set in environment.conf, you need to edit your environment.conf for all of your environments.

nano -w /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/{environment_name}/environment.conf

```
modulepath = '/var/opt/puppet/modules:/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules:/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/modules'
```

BTW: For Puppet v6.0 '/etc/puppetlabs/code/modules' may be a better choice for a global modules directory.

Comment: I think this is stupid default behaviour. Why on earth would I ever want modules I install from forge available in only one environment? Great answer though, thank you!

Comment: @AndyFoster you may want to see whether a module will work on your testing/staging environment before you use it on your production environment. I guess, the default is production, because Puppet comes with only one environment when you install it: production.

Answer (score 0):

```
puppet module --modulepath=/var/opt/puppet/modules install foo
```

Comment: I *did* say that I want them to install there by default. Is this thing really so difficult to use that I have to specify that switch every time?

Comment: p.s. I've specified `modulepath` in the config prior to asking this question and it didn't work. 1) It complained about deprecation and 2) it still installed to `production/modules`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using environment config sections.
So, you can set modulepath in each environment’s section of puppet.conf. Like...

[main]

--

environmentpath = /var/opt/puppet/environments

basemodulepath = /var/opt/puppet/modules

--

[production]

--

--

[dev]

--

--

If that setting is absent in a given environment, Puppet will fall back to the global value of the modulepath setting(/var/opt/puppet/modules).
Or you can specify the separate module path for each directory sections.
Hope you got the answer...

Comment: Well, no. I don't have _any_ configuration specified for the individual environments. They are all using the defaults from `[main]`, which is quoted in my question. But `puppet module install foo` is installing to `/var/opt/puppet/environments/production/modules` instead of `/var/opt/puppet/modules`.

Comment: As you mentioned " It's configured to use environments" in the question, you are using directory environment and default environment is being created as production....  This is default behavior.
So, you can define separate settings for every environment.
If you are not defining any separate settings it will use /var/opt/puppet/environments/$environment/modules directory.

Solution is, you need to define specific environment settings..

[production]
modulepath=/var/opt/puppet/modules

Comment: Hope you got the answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Each environment can have its own 'modulepath' if you create an `environment.conf` file within the environment directory.

More information on environments can be found on the Puppet labs website here:

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/env_environments.html